# Which openam config file stores the user data details?

Tags: openam

I know that the Openam stores its configuration and user details in the xml files in the config folder.Can anyone specify which all files are used to store the user data information?

Answer (score 0):

OpenAM user data is almost always stored in an external LDAP directory, such as the ForgeRock Directory Server.  The xml files you see are only for initial service configuration.